# Relational operators between big sparse matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have two big sparse double matrices in Matlab:

- `P` with dimension `1048576 x 524288`
- `I` with dimension `1048576 x 524288`

I want to find the number of entrances `i,j` such that `P(i,j)<=I(i,j)`

Naively I tried to run

```
 n=sum(sum(P<=I));
```

but it is extremely slow (I had to shut down Matlab because it was running since forever and I wasn't able to stop it).

Is there any other more efficient way to proceed or what I want to do is unfeasible?

Comment: Depends highly in the sparsity of `P<=I`. If its true all the time, then the answer is a "full" sparse matrix, taking about 2.5~3x more memory that if it was a normal full matrix. If this is expected, perhaps looping, even if its row-wise, is a better idea, as likely what it is making this operation slow is the need of memory, not the arithmetics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From some simple tests,

```
n = numel(P) - nnz(P>I);
```

seems to be faster than `sum(sum(P<=I))` or even `nnz(P<=I)`. The reason is probably that the sparse matrix `P<=I` has many more nonzero entries than `P>I`, and thus requires more memory.

Example:

```
>> P = sprand(10485, 52420, 1e-3);
>> I = sprand(10485, 52420, 1e-3);
>> tic, disp(sum(sum(P<=I))); toc
   (1,1)      549074582
Elapsed time is 3.529121 seconds.
>> tic, disp(nnz(P<=I)); toc
   549074582
Elapsed time is 3.538129 seconds.
>> tic, disp(nnz(P<=I)); toc
   549074582
Elapsed time is 3.499927 seconds.
>> tic, disp(numel(P) - nnz(P>I)); toc
   549074582
Elapsed time is 0.010624 seconds.
```

Of course this highly depends on the matrix sizes and density.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using indices of nonzero elements:

```
xp = find(P);
xi = find(I);
vp = nonzeros(P);
vi = nonzeros(I);
[s,ia,ib] = intersect(xp,xi);

iia = true(numel(vp),1);
iia(ia)=false;
iib = true(numel(vi),1);
iib(ib) = false;
n = sum(vp(ia) <= vi(ib))+sum(vp(iia)<0)+sum(vi(iib)>0)-(numel(xp)+numel(xi)-numel(s))+numel(P);
```